# How to run looping task untill other task is finished

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I found many questions addressing how to sequence tasks and waiting until all tasks finish, but with this topic, I found only 1 question from 2016 with no answers.

I'm processing a large text file in my project and I want to indicate that this process is running with the text being displayed with changing number of dots after the "Processing" text. I got to the point, where the intended looping task is working until a long working task finishes and the proper field in the VM is updated, but I can't make looping task to be delayed so dots are changing in the way it's seen.

In other words - the same functionality as when a loader is displayed while data are being retrieved from the HTTP request.

```cs
public void SetRawTextFromAbsPath(string path)
{
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        return;
    }

    var rawText = "Processing";
    bool IsReadingFileFinished = false;

    Task<string> getRawTextFromAbsPath = Task.Run(() => {
        var result = FileProcessingServices.GetRawFileText(path);
        IsReadingFileFinished = true;
        return result;
        });

    Task updateProgressText = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (!IsReadingFileFinished)
        {
            rawText = await Task.Run(() => ProcessingTextChange(rawText));
            SelectedFileRaw = rawText;
        }
    });

    Task.WaitAll(getRawTextFromAbsPath, updateProgressText);

    SelectedFileRaw = completeRawText.Result;
}

public string ProcessingTextChange(string text)
{
    Task.Delay(100);
    var dotsCount = text.Count<char>(ch => ch == '.');

    return dotsCount < 6 ? text + "." : text.Replace(".", "");
}
```

After learning from all the answers, I come up with this solution:

```cs
private const string PROGRESS = "Progress";
private const int PROGRESS_DELAY = 200;

        public async void RunProgressTextUpdate()
        {
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            if (!IsRunning)
            {
                UpdateProgressTextTask(cts.Token);
                string longTaskText = await Task.Run(() => LongTask(cts));
                await Task.Delay(PROGRESS_DELAY);
                ProgressText = longTaskText;
            }                  
        }

        private void UpdateProgressTextTask(CancellationToken token)
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                ProgressText = PROGRESS;
                while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(PROGRESS_DELAY);
                    var dotsCount = ProgressText.Count<char>(ch => ch == '.');

                    ProgressText = dotsCount < 6 ? ProgressText + "." : ProgressText.Replace(".", "");
                }
            });

        }

        private string LongTask(CancellationTokenSource cts)
        {
            var result = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(5000);
                cts.Cancel();
                return "Long task finished.";
            });

            return result.Result;
        }
```

Comment: Firstly, you should be using the *async and await pattern* for this. Secondly you could signal to the second task that first is finished in many ways, like a cancellation token, thirdly, you shouldn't really be using  `Task.Factory.StartNew` and should prefer the more modern `Task.Run`. Additionally, you should never really be calling `Result` or `Wait`on a task, see the async and await pattern

Comment: 1. Get rid of all the [`StartNew`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)s. 2. Draw your moving dots using a [`Progress` object](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html) that you would pass to the processing routine. 3. `Task.Delay(100)` is a no-op. `await Task.Delay(100)` would wait for 100 ms (not that it solves your problem though, because with a `Progress` object you wouldn't use it).

Comment: @MichaelRandall - I understand what you mean, I put together this code from various posts I found and I agree with you. But these changes would not solve my problem I think.

Comment: @GSerg Thank you, its good link, I was reading this series as well, but did missed this article. With this, I would achieve similar thing like with BackgroundWorker, but it indeed won't solve my problem, because I need reporting being independent of the long-running task progress (I don't know how long it will take).

Comment: No matter how long it takes, that's the whole point of async. If you don't want to use `async`/`await` syntax, you could call `ContinueWith` and pass into another `Task` which will be started when the first is resolved.

Comment: @VRoxa I would be totally fine to use async-await syntax, I just don't know how to put it together :) But I don't need to start a task when other is resolved (thats like, super easy and there is tons of examples around), I need one task to be looping until the other finishes.

Comment: Then instantiate a `CancelationTokenSource` provide the `Token` to both of the `Task`. The first `Task` just calls the `cts` to `Cancel` when it finishes.

Comment: @VRoxa - yes, I know I have to do it in this way, but I'm so stuck in all those samples and articles I found, that I cant put it together :( If you could provide minimalistic working code sample, it would sure solve it. Please?

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311829/why-cant-i-mark-my-title-as-solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every way of creating `Task` and running them is overloaded to expect a `CancellationToken`. *CancellationTokens* are, unsurprinsignly, structs that allows us to cancel *Tasks*.

Having this two methods

```
public void DelayedWork()
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // Simulate some async work
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    });
}

public void LoopingUntilDelayedWorkFinishes()
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        int i = 0;
        // We keep looping until the Token is not cancelled
        while (true) // May be?
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{++i} iteration ...");
        }
    });
}
```

We want `LoopingUntilDelayedWorkFinishes` to stop looping when `DelayedWork` finishes (well, naming was quite obvious).

We can provide a `CancellationToken` to our `LoopingUntilDelayedWorkFinishes` method. So it will keep looping until it is cancelled.

```
public void LoopingUntilDelayedWorkFinishes(CancellationToken token)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        int i = 0;
        // We keep looping until the Token is not cancelled
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{++i} iteration ...");
        }
    }, token); // This is the overload expecting the Token
}
```

Okay, working. We can control this `CancellationToken` by extracting from a `CancellationTokenSource`, which controls its `CancellationToken`.

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
p.LoopingUntilDelayedWorkFinishes(cts.Token);
```

And now, we need our `DelayedWork` to cancel the token when it finishes.

```
public void DelayedWork(CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // Simulate some async work
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        // Once it is done, we cancel.
        cts.Cancel();
    });
}
```

That is how we could call the methods.

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
p.DelayedWork(cts);
p.LoopingUntilDelayedWorkFinishes(cts.Token);
```

The call order between `DelayedWork` and `LoopingUntilDelayedWorkFinishes` is not that important (in that case).

Maybe `LoopingUntilDelayedWorkFinishes` can return a `Task` and the await for it later on, I don't know. I just depends on our needs.

There are tons of ways to achieve this. The environment arround `Task` is so bast and the API is quite confusing sometimes.
Here's how you could do it. Maybe some smart use of `async/await` syntax would improve the solution I gave. But, here's the main idea.

Hope it helps.